# upgrade to 9.0.1 disabled App store and other apps

Tags: ios, settings, cellular-data

latest update not only disallows cellular settings to stay set but also disabled the App store. (iPhone 4S) I can't even begin to figure out how to fix this.cannot set "do not disturb" to manual, like it was before the upgrade either.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating to iOS 9.0.2, it's yet more bug fixes.

[image]

Comment: update 9.0.2 came to my phone at 3am last night - it fixed this issue.

Comment: @DonnaM Great! Please click the green checkmark to the left of my answer to accept my answer, it helps me out.